# How do I get WWW::Mechanize to work?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

This script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

$mech->get( "http://www.google.com" );
print $mech->content;
```

Produces this error message:

> Error GETing http://www.google.com:
>   Can't connect to www.google.com:80
>   (connect: Unknown error) at
>   D:\PERL\try.pl line 5

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7):

From your error message I see that you're on a Windows box (D:\PERL\try.pl). Maybe the Windows firewall doesn't trust Perl to access the internet and blocks its traffic?

You might get lucky adding a rule allowing perl.exe access to the internet in the Windows firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Did it work before? This code works on my Linux box.

1. It could be that you have no internet connection.
2. Maybe Google blocked you.

Comment: no i have internet connection and am getting this error for all the sites.... even if i try to open a html file in my system it throws me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Might be your firewall like Olfan said or you might need to have to use a proxy in your environment.

Comment: can u tell me how can i use the proxy please..in my code.. also how can i set my firewall settings in order to work my code

Comment: Please referr to the LWP::UserAgent documentation for information regarding the proxy: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent
Since I don't know the first thing about Windows (let alone what personal firewall you are using), I can't help you with the firewall.